# adapter.class and display.class will what is Context?

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

After changing my list adapter to a recycleview adapter it turns out that lestin to OnItem click has never been harder :/ I tried every single method but all not work because which i know nothing about `Context`. Like starting a new activity on click in adapter class:

```
new intent(context, Single.class)

 new intent(getActivity(), Single.class)

new intent(getContext(), Single.class)

new intent(getApplicationContext(), Single.class)

new intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Single.class)


new intent(activity.this, Single.class)

new intent(this, Single.class)

new intent(activity.class, Single.class)
```

All above codes can't be resolved,
I think i should creat somthing called context?
Please help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an context parameter to constructor of your adapter and save it as a member like this:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

and on your click listener,call

```
new intent(this.mContext, Single.class)
```

And when you create the adapter in your activity,like this:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
```

Comment: Aha actulay i tried to use adapter context: listItem, but without "this." i wilI try this when the power come

Comment: Actually forgot to said that the callback class is intended to be implemented by a Fragment or an Activity. You can then create your intent in such objects.

Comment: I put : this.Activity = activity then used activity as context, its being resolved but startactivity(intent); is not

Comment: @H4F,use `this.mContext.startActivity(intent)` instead.`startActivity` is method of class `Context`.

Comment: I went back to listview with shadow insted of recycleview

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know more about the differences between each type of Context, I recommend you [this reading](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/).

What you need to do is create a callback class that will be passed through the adapter constructor. In the `onBindViewHolder` method, create a click listener on whatever `View` you need, and in the `onClick` method, just call your callback.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ...

    private MyCallback mCallback;

    public MyAdapter(..., MyCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
        ...
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UniversityItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallback.onItemClicked(v, position);
            }
        });

    ...
```

Comment: I tried this before, getPostion() works in onBindViewHolder but when i come to start activity the first part cant be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Context is built-in class in Android,look [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html),and `Activity` and `ApplicationContext` are subclass of it.so you can use `activity.this` or `getApplicationContext` to apply methods which need `Context` parameter.

Comment: @H4F,did you call this method in `Activity` or `Fragment`?

Comment: None of that, in adapter class, im using recycleview

Comment: All methodes i foumd to make onitemclick in recycleview was coding in the adapter class

Comment: @H4F,I got! Your current problem is how to get the `context` parameter to used in start a activity,right?If so,there are two methods.**1.pass an `context` parameter to construtor of your adapter and save it as a member; 2.abstract your click method to an interface and implements this interface in `activity`**.

Comment: Can you please explain with codes, im like 4/10 in programing, advanced nope :D. i didnt understand any thing of what you mentioned

Comment: What im tring to do is  creat a new intent to start a new activity for that clicked item. With normal listview adapter i put the reqular onclick code in the list activity and works fine. But in recycleview codes "as i have seen" must be writeed inside the adapter activity thus when i try those codes it cant recuqnize the startoff activity